# Appcelerator : Hide Statusbar on Splashscreen , iOS

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Repost of [this](https://archive.appcelerator.com/topic/3581/ios-hide-statusbar-on-splashscreen) question of the old **Appcelerator Q&A Archive**

Yes , the problem is still the same. In my new apps i can't longer **hide the statusbar** on the **splash screen**.

I tried every possible combination of these properties (in the **tiapp.xml**)

```
<statusbar-hidden>true/false</statusbar-hidden>
<fullscreen>true/false</fullscreen>
<navbar-hidden>true/false</navbar-hidden>
```

Comment: Have tried after cleaning build and removing app from simulator?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, these attributes don't affect iOS apps. In your tiapp.xml, add the following:

```
<ios>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </plist>
</ios>
```

[Reference](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/tiapp.xml_and_timodule.xml_Reference-section-29004921_tiapp.xmlandtimodule.xmlReference-UIStatusBarHidden)

Comment: I had not seen the presence of these new properties, added with the latest SDK , this solve the problem , thanks